# .Pls file parsing

Tags: iphone

Iam creating and radio application in which i have to check the authentication and after successful login i get .pls file in which there is actual url which has to be played so 
anybody know how to parse .pls file and get the url inside the .pls file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a WWEMAC.pls file in main bundle. In which more than one url exist and I have to extract only those URLs and add them in array in string format. Following code worked for me.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WWEMAC" ofType:@"pls"];
NSError *errorReading;
NSArray *linesOfText = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorReading] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"Reading error  %@",errorReading);
NSString *completeDataInStr = [linesOfText componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:completeDataInStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [completeDataInStr length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",match.URL];
    NSLog(@"URL str = %@",str);
}
return matches;
```

Comment: WWEMAC.pls file contains are something like this

[streamlist]
File1=http://stream.com:80/WWW_PC
File1=http://stream.com:81/WWW_PC
File2=http://stream.com:82/WWW_PC
File3=http://stream.com:83/WWW_PC
File4=http://stream.com:84/WWW_PC
File5=http://stream.com:85/WWW_PC
Title1=WWEMAC_PC
Length1=-1
NumberOfEntries=5
Version=5

And returned array (named as matches here) contains only URLs from .pls file.